# How can I make this more efficient? I am trying to refactor my program, what methods could make this more effective?

Tags: c++

What could I do to make these functions more efficient? (Shorter, clearer, faster). I am trying to code refactor my program and make it cleaner. I was just wondering if there are any better methods I could use for this min and max latitude functions. They are quite simple as all they do is compare and return. Are there any better ways to write these functions?

```
degrees minLatitude() const
{
    emptyCheck();

    degrees minLat = positions.front().latitude();
    for (const Position& pos : positions)
    {
        minLat = std::min(minLat, pos.latitude());
    }
    return minLat;
}

degrees maxLatitude() const
{
    emptyCheck();

    degrees maxLat = positions.front().latitude();
    for (const Position& pos : positions)
    {
        maxLat = std::max(maxLat,pos.latitude());
    }
    return maxLat;
 }
```

Comment: `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` (with a custom compare) would seem obvious improvements. Apart from that, there's not enough context to tell.

Comment: If you need both result at once `std::minmax_element` has a little better complexity (but bot necessary faster ;) ) than calling each method.